# Flutter: Nested ListView Overflow warning

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a nested ListView like this.

```
  AnimatedContainer(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
            height:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.30,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                          width: 300,
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20,
                              child: Row(
                               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                               children: [
                                Text('hmm'),
                                Row(
                                  ListView(     
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                   children: [
                                        Container(
                                      height: 40,
                                      width: 200,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                       ),
                                       Container(
                                       height: 40,
                                       width: 200,
                                       color: Colors.white,
                                         ),
                                        Container(
                                         height: 40,
                                          width: 200,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                         ),
                                            ]
```

I am trying to have a scroll effect inside the Container. However, I am getting `The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal.`

First, I'd thought it was because of the `Container` widget did not have height and width. But it doesn't look like it was a problem since I still have the error. I've tried to add `Expanded` widget or another `Container` widget to set the height and width. None of them fixing the `Overflow` warning.

What should I have to adjust in order to make the `ListView` vertically scrollable inside the `AnimatedContainer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try replace the Row that wrapper the ListView with horizontal direction, with a Container or something with fixed height.